# How to change the "sonata project" link in SonataAdmin?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a problem with SonataAdminBundle, I don't find how to change the "sonata project" link in the left board.

I have "My title" + one image and under there is "sonata project".

How can I change this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to customize the content of the block under *Sonata Admin* (by default it's a link with text *sonata project*), you have to modify your  <kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>  file by adding this:

```
sonata_admin:
    # ...
    templates:
        # Override default template
        layout: AcmeAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
```

Then create the <kbd>standard_layout.html.twig</kbd> file in the <kbd>src/Acme/AdminBundle/Resources/views</kbd> directory:

```
{# src/Acme/AdminBundle/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig #}
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block side_bar_after_nav %}
    <p class="text-center"><a href="{{ path('your_route') }}">Route name</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

This will replace the [default content of this block](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/0a3a7adfc907da0b4a7d5c542f6157aac4d33942/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig#L216).

---

If you don't want to place the file in a bundle, use this path in  <kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd> : `layout: "::standard_layout.html.twig"` ant put the file in <kbd>app/Resources/views</kbd>.

---

And if you want to change the title *Sonata Admin*, add this to your  <kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd> file:

```
sonata_admin:
    # ...
    title: My Name
```

Comment: Works good, but I would add it in the `app/config/config.yml` and not in the `app/config/parameters.yml`. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html) why