# Customiza Sonata left sidebar

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

[image: Sonata Admin Area]

I would like to add these links in left sidebar but i do not know how :S I've been trying but none :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the "sonata project" link in SonataAdmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827713/how-to-change-the-sonata-project-link-in-sonataadmin)

Answer (score 1):

In YourBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml
add :

```
services:
    tabssoft.admin.company:
        class: Tabssoft\CompanyBundle\Admin\CompanyAdmin
        tags:
           - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "General", label: "Company" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Tabssoft\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company
            - TabssoftCompanyBundle:CompanyCRUD
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [TabssoftCompanyBundle]]

    tabssoft.admin.job:
        class: Tabssoft\CompanyBundle\Admin\JobAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "General", label: "Job" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Tabssoft\CompanyBundle\Entity\Job
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [TabssoftCompanyBundle]]
```

Then in app/config/config.yml under `imports:` add:

```
- { resource: @TabssoftCompanyBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }
```

Then in app/config/sonata/sonata_admin.yml under `groups:` add:

```
sonata.admin.group.tabssoft:
    label:           General
    label_catalogue: TabssoftCompanyBundle
    icon:            '<i class="fa fa-th"></i>'
    items:
        - tabssoft.admin.company
        - tabssoft.admin.job
```

clear caсhe

Comment: This is good when i use whole sonata project but i'm only using the sonata adminBundle